# How to fix error: "class, interface, or enum expected" when defining a Map outside of a class?

Tags: java, android, dictionary

For my own `Logger` class I want to define a map to map the priority number back to a meaningful string like follows:

```
static Map<int, String> map = new HashMap<int, String>();
map.put(2, "VERBOSE");
map.put(3, "DEBUG");
map.put(4, "INFO");
map.put(5, "WARN");
map.put(6, "ERROR");
```

I wonder if there might be a function that does this automatically? But I do now know every function there is.

However, I define the lines just before my class definition, and then I get the error:

```
Error:(14, 8) error: class, interface, or enum expected
```

and not sure what it means (maybe I cannot declare variables outside a class?). I also tried to define the map inside the class, but then the `put` method cannot be resolved. I also notice, that I have not imported a `Map` module, and AndroidStudio does not seem to require a `Map` module (i.e. the name 'Map' is not red and underlined).

I am very confused (as usual); I just want to get a String "ERROR" if the priority-value is 6 and so on.

What am I doing wrong in my case...?

Comment: Not int; use Integer for the key.

Comment: Your variable must be inside a class. In Java everything must be inside a class. Your statements (`map.put...`) must be inside a method.

Comment: Google static initializers.

Comment: What do you mean by "outside a class"?  The only conceivable place outside a class where you could declare a variable of any kind is *inside* an interface.  And you cannot define non-`final` (or non-`static`) variables inside an interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> maybe I cannot declare variables outside a class?

Correct.

Use:

```
class Foo {
  static Map<Integer, String> PRIORITY_LABELS = new HashMap<>();

  static {
    PRIORITY_LABELS.put(2, "VERBOSE");
    PRIORITY_LABELS.put(3, "DEBUG");
    PRIORITY_LABELS.put(4, "INFO");
    PRIORITY_LABELS.put(5, "WARN");
    PRIORITY_LABELS.put(6, "ERROR");
  }

  // rest of class goes here
}
```

> I also notice, that I have not imported a Map module, and AndroidStudio does not seem to require a Map module (i.e. the name 'Map' is not red and underlined).

That is because Android Studio does not know what to do with that code. Once you move them into the class, *then* Android Studio will realize that you are trying to use `Map` and `HashMap` and will ask you to import them.

Comment: I had `Map` and `HashMap` inside the class, and android did not ask to import anything. Anyway, your solution seems to work...

Comment: @Alex: Perhaps you have `import java.util.*;` or something that bulk-imports a bunch of classes and interfaces, including `Map` and `HashMap`.

Comment: @CommonsWare hello sir, Sorry to comment in between please I need a logic to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576258/how-to-keep-user-logged-in-always-connected-with-server

Comment: It can be an encoding problem. check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665663/android-studio-error-class-interface-or-enum-expeted/53350503#53350503